# I'm trying to get elements and add them inside of a new element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get data-attributes from html on the page and create a list with the information.

```
$('.year').each(function(){
    let year = '<li>' + $(this).attr('data-year') + '</li>';
    let years = '<ul>' + year + '</ul>';
});
```

I'm getting this

```
<ul><li></li></ul>
<ul><li></li></ul>
<ul><li></li></ul>
```

I need this

```
<ul>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please add the html part as well

Comment: The html doesn't matter because I'm trying to create it with jQuery. I'm able to get the data that I need, but I can't get all the lis in the ul.

Comment: Define `years` outside the loop, after it finishes.

Answer (score 1):

the ul is inside the .each function() thus for each iteration the ul element is added

Answer (score 1):

```
let year='';
$('.year').each(function(){
    year += '<li>' + $(this).attr('data-year') + '</li>';
});
let years = '<ul>' + year + '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the unordered list opening and closing tags should not be inside the each() loop.

Here's how I might code it to work correctly:

```
var years = "";
    
$('.year').each(function(){
    years += '<li>' + $(this).attr('data-year') + '</li>';
});
    
years = '<ul>' + years + '</ul>';
```

Comment: @Harsh Gundecha - Yes. Please tell me how that's a problem? The end value of 'years' will be an html snippet of a correctly formatted unordered list. That's what the OP asked for.